# Problema com addEventListener

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Olá, pessoal.
Eu sei que já existem diversas dúvidas relacionadas ao addEventListener no site, porém já tentei diversas soluções e até agora nada. Resolvi postar meu código aqui para ver se dessa forma a solução vem.
Vale ressaltar que eu executei tanto em arquivo externo, quanto direto no HTML.

```
<form>

        <div class="container float-md-center float-sm-center">
          <div class="row">
          <h1 class="nomeprojeto">Cadastro</h1>
          <div class="nome">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput" class="form-label">Nome Completo</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" placeholder="Nome">
          </div>
          <div class="email2">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput3" class="form-label">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="nome@exemplo.com">
          </div>
          <div class="senha2">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput2" class="form-label">Senha</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="*****">
          </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="cadastrar btn btn-primary position-relative top-50 start-50 translate-middle">Cadastrar</button>
          </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <script src="novo-usuario.js"></script>
```

```
    let usuario = document.querySelector("#usuario");
    let senha = document.querySelector("#password");
    let email = document.querySelector("#email");

    var cadastrar = document.querySelector("#cadastrar");

    cadastrar.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let dados = {
            usuario: usuario.value,
            senha: senha.value,
            email: email.value
        };

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Seu script quebra ao chamar o método `addEventListener` do seu botão cadastrar, porque ele esta nulo. Em seu `HTML` vc criou um botão mais não definiu o atributo `id="cadastrar"`, o querySellector não encontra elemento no `DOM` com `id=cadastrar`.

Outra coisa o evento `submit` não irá funcionar no botão, experimente o evento `click`;